# ResponseText from JavaScript Ajax Class in another class method?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I wrote a (for now simplyfied) Ajax Class in Javascript for Get Requests. I want to call this Ajax.get() method from another class that inserts the xhr.responseText into some content like a modal oder alert. Unfortunally I am unable to solve the problem of getting this responseText into my other class' function since the this-keyword has the wrong scope and the xhr-variable is not accessible from outside the function.

So far I have messed around with everything but I couldn't find a way to solve my problem.

```
class Ajax
{
    static get ({url, target, success = () => {})
    {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.onload = function ()
        {
            if ( this.status == 200 )
            {
                success(this.responseText);
                // do something yet undefined with the responseText
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
}
class Modal
{
    static createModal (body)
    { 
        // creates a Modal with the value of "body", e.g.
        alert(body);
    }

    static getModal( )
    {
        let modalBody = Ajax.get
        ({
            url : 'text.txt',
            success : Modal.createModal(/*???*/);
        });
    }
}
</script>
<button onclick="Modal.getModal()">Get dnamic Modal</button>
```

I want the modal (simplyfied: alert) to have the text from the Ajax.get()'s xhr.response. So I need to pass an unknown variable or do whatever. The closest success so far was 'undefined' (i.e. no syntax / parsing error).

Comment: You need to pass a callback function.

Comment: How would the code look then?